JavaScript ¿cómo se pueden crear 4 artículos dinámicos cuando cargue la página (onload) en un section y no en un body?
Necesito crear 4 articles mediante una función que los cree dentro de un section destino (display: grid) al cargar la página. Se trata de un desafío de la formación y no se me ocurre como. La función se ejecuta al ponerla en el body, pero, obviamente destruye toda la página dejando solo los artículos generados. Y el desafio consiste en que se mantenga la página web. Como nos encontramos en el módulo de evaluación de errores y tras llevar horas dándole vueltas no se si es posible o simplemente el maestro se está quedando con nosotros proponiendo un imposible.
Código HTML:
<section class="practice grid4-25">
<article onload="articulosDinamicos()"></article>
</section>

La función está metida en su correspondiente .js y funciona perfectamente, solo, que solo al colocarla en el body con onload o addEventListener. La section debería mantenerse ya que es una grid de 4 ya preparada para coger los artículos. El artículo del ejemplo puede desaparecer sin problemas.
Función JavaScript
function articulosDinamicos() {
    for (let i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        document.write('<article class="article-errores-javascript1"><h7 class="text-center margenb10">Artículo ' + (i+1) + '</h7><img src="assets/images/errores_javascript1-article.jpg"><div>Artículo creado de manera automática en la carga de la web.</div></article>');
    }

¡Muchísimas gracias por adelantado!

Observando el problema que tienes es porque el evento onload se ejecuta en algunos elementos del DOM, por ejemplo en el body o en imagenes, lo que tienes que hacer es colocar el evento en la etiqueta body de esta manera:


function articulosDinamicos() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    document.write('<article class="article-errores-javascript1"><h7 class="text-center margenb10">Artículo ' + (i + 1) + '</h7><img src="assets/images/errores_javascript1-article.jpg"><div>Artículo creado de manera automática en la carga de la web.</div></article><br>');
  }
}
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Título de la página</title>
</head>

<body onload="articulosDinamicos()">
  <section class="practice grid4-25">
  </section>
</body>

</html>



Entendido esto, no es la manera, ni la mejor practica mezclar código HTML y JS, para esto te dejo este ejemplo que a mi parecer es mejor:


//FUNCION QUE DETECTA LA CARGA COMPLETA DEL DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //SE LLAMA A LA FUNCION QUE CREA LOS ARTICULOS
  articulosDinamicos()
});

function articulosDinamicos() {
  //OBTENEMOS EL CONTENEDOR DONDE SE PINTARAN LOS ARTICULOS MEDIANTE SU ID
  var section = document.getElementById('section');
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var articles = '<article class="article-errores-javascript1"><h7 class="text-center margenb10">Artículo ' + (i + 1) + '</h7><img src="assets/images/errores_javascript1-article.jpg"><div>Artículo creado de manera automática en la carga de la web.</div></article><br>'
    //ESCRIBE LOS ARTICULOS EN EL ELEMENTO DEL DOM INDICADO
    section.innerHTML += articles;
  }
}
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Título de la página</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="section" class="practice grid4-25">
  </section>
</body>

</html>



Ahora si forzosamente tienes que utilizar el evento onload podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera, donde el evento se detecta desde tu JS:


window.onload = function articulosDinamicos() {
  //OBTENEMOS EL ELEMENTO MEDIANTE SU ID
  var section = document.getElementById("section");
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    //ESCRIBE LOS ARTICULOS EN EL ELEMENTO DEL DOM INDICADO
    section.innerHTML +=
      '<article class="article-errores-javascript1"><h7 class="text-center margenb10">Artículo ' +
      (i + 1) +
      '</h7><img src="assets/images/errores_javascript1-article.jpg"><div>Artículo creado de manera automática en la carga de la web.</div></article><br>';
  }
};
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Título de la página</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="section" class="practice grid4-25">
  </section>
</body>

</html>



Dime si te funciono, te dejo este link para que entiendas mejor como funciona el evento.

Simplemente sensacional. ¡Funcionó a la primera! La verdad es que el ejercicio es un tanto raro, puesto que lo mas normal es colocar un "onload" en el body. Hoy empezamos la última unidad formativa: evaluación de errores. Me imagino que el profesor nos quiere hacer ver errores y malas praxis.
Me encantaría poder votarte, pero, me registré hoy y me pide llevar 15 días registrado para ello. Pero, en cuanto pase los 15 días busco la pregunta en mi perfil y te voto positivo.
¡Un fuerte abrazo desde Barcelona!

Excelente, mucha suerte.
